# should we check for multicollinearity when building a discrimination analysis?

Tags: r, classification, mathematical-statistics

In fact, I have two questions:

1- do we need to check for the multicollinearity when we deal with linear discrimination analysis?

2- how to solve those variables which are multi-collinear?

Lets say I want to perform Linear Discrimination Analysis and I have a matrix of 100 samples and 10 variables. should I check for the multicollinearity? I did already and I found half of my variables are multi-collinear. How to solve this problem (if there is any way to solve it in R, I would appreciate your answer)

I found some packages which does the job but I am not sure if I am solving the problem correctly

what I did is like this

```
library(pracma)
A <- matrix(c(0,-4,2, 6,-3,-2, 8,1,-1), 3, 3, byrow=TRUE)
gs <- gramSchmidt(A)
```

output consists of two matrices Q and R, Q orthonormal and R upper triangular
so, if I use Q, my problem will be solved ?